# Azure B1Is nonfunctional upon creation

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I have an almost static site that i was happy hosting on Storage blob. However, i need to have php script run to support email communication through the contact html form.

So i decided to buy the smallest VM which is B1Is   which has 1 CPU and 0.5 GB of memory.  I RDP to the server and to my astonishment I cannot even open one file or folder or Task Manager without waiting endlessly before the "Out of memory ...please try to close programs or restart all"!

The Azure team should not sell such a VM if it will be nonfunctional from the get go.  Note that i installed ZERO programs on it.

All i want is php and setup the site on IIS. And add a certificate license to it.  NO Database or any other programs will run.

What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is because "1 B1ls is supported only on Linux"  based on the notes on their page.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sizes-general